# Object not found error when trying to create convert file format job from Cloud Dataflow console

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a "Convert file formats between Avro, Parquet & csv" job from a template using the console, but I get an error that the input object doesn't exist:

[image: screenshot]

It seems to me that this input box is wrongly expects an (existing) GCS location, rather than a pattern. On other templates that allow for wildcards in input you get a normal text box, not one with a browse button.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This looks to be a bug. Could you please use gcloud to launch the issue until there is a fix? You can fill in the form then click on the "equivalent gcloud" command button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please report this issue [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) for further investigation? Meanwhile, you can use Peter Kim's recommendation to launch the template through gcloud command.